# How to remove the white space in the top corner of a library page?

Tags: library

I have created a new library. It works fine. I enabled the "Metadata Navigation" and now I see alot of white space above my library. See printscreen. How can I reduce this white space? When I disable "Metadata Navigation" the white space is gone.

[image]

When I decrease the width (from 100% to 99%) in the page source in the debug window (IE/F12) of the html table it is fixed:

[image]

how to implement that the width of this table needs to be 99%?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding a content editor webpart. Inside this content editor webpart I refer to a custom css. Inside this css I have a fixed width of the left navigation.